# Creating bidirectional PageView scrolling in Flutter?

Tags: widget, scrollview, flutter

How would you implement bi-directional page scrolling functionality in Flutter?  Multiple PageViews in a given Scaffold don't seem to work, nor do nested PageViews.  My feeling is that NestedScrollView might offer a solution, but I'm struggling to figure out the implementation.

Comment: Try this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bidirectional_scroll_view or see its source code.

Comment: @RolandoUrquiza That package looks fairly weak to me, i.e. unidiomatic.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWkysCKh2uY   
    Flutter Challenge: Card Flip Carousel, by Fluttery    Published on May 31, 2018 .  
    https://github.com/matthew-carroll/flutter_ui_challenge_flip_carousel    Matthew has some pretty awesome stuff. Check out his github repo.  You can easily analyse his code to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

**Multi Directional PageView:**

You could potentially create some sort of trickery for this, i.e. set amount of pages to 2000 and then set the initial page as 1000. Therefore creating a PageView with 1000 +/- left right scrolls?

**Widget:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future<void>.delayed(Duration.zero, () => _diaryBloc.buildComplete());

    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: PageView.builder(
        controller: _diaryBloc.pageController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return _buildPage(_diaryBloc.getDateFromPosition(position));
        },
        itemCount: 2000,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**BLoC or other controller**

```
  final PageController pageController = PageController();
  final int initialPage = 1000;

  Future<void> buildComplete() async {
    pageController.jumpToPage(initialPage);
  }

  DateTime getDateFromPosition(int position) {
    if (position < 0) {
      return currentDateTime.subtract(Duration(days: position - initialPage));
    } else {
      return currentDateTime.add(Duration(days: position - initialPage));
    }
  }
```

Might not be the ideal but is extremely simple and seems to work well.